# Git merge resulting in unreasonable conflicts

Tags: git

I am essentially getting conflicts on ALMOST all files that merge from current_iteration into my branch. This has been maddening and have had many people look and scratch their heads with amazement.

I am currently working on a mac with git version `2.18.0`. My counterparts are all working on Windows git version `2.12.2.windows.2`.

**MacBook Configuration**

```
macbook-pro:~ chris$ git config -l
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.email=chris.hinshaw@foo.com
user.name=Chris Hinshaw
user.autocrlf=false
```

**Windows Configuration**

```
C:> git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
help.format=html
rebase.autosquash=true
http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/…
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
credential.helper=manager
merge.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.cmd="C:\\Program Files\\KDiff3\\kdiff3" $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE -o $MERGED
difftool.kdiff3.path="C:\\Program Files\\KDiff3\\kdiff3"
difftool.kdiff3.keepbackup=false
difftool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
alias.lg=!git lg1
alias.lg1=!git lg1-specific --all
alias.lg2=!git lg2-specific --all
alias.lg3=!git lg3-specific --all
alias.lg1-specific=log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)'
alias.lg2-specific=log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)'
alias.lg3-specific=log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(bold cyan)(committed: %cD)%C(reset) %C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset)%n''          %C(dim white)- %an <%ae> %C(reset) %C(dim white)(committer: %cn <%ce>)%C(reset)'
core.whitespace=cr-at-eol
core.autocrlf=true
credential.helper=manager
http.emptyauth=true
```

**Current Iteration Branch Changes**

Here I am checking out current_iteration and making sure it is completely up to
date. I show that the difference was a one line change where the
component annotation was removed from the class.

```
macbook-pro:devel chris$ git checkout current_iteration
macbook-pro:devel chris$ git pull origin 

commit 81dea298657c882a5c32ee3f30b459643035024e
Author: Them
Date:   Wed Aug 1 11:12:12 2018 -0500


commit 0676ffd81a83cfbdf18a3b1fc93f31439d7e3a00
Author: Me
Date:   Mon Jul 30 18:01:53 2018 -0500


commit 0d8f7a2dfe35d43ef03af339694479189ff86b79
Author: Me
Date:   Wed Jul 25 15:04:44 2018 -0500
```

Diff that will be applied to my current branch

```
git diff 81dea~1 ./somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java
./somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.javaindex 08c3e66c..f0864c52 100644
--- a/somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java
+++ b/somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java
@@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.Map;
 import java.util.function.Supplier;

-@Component
+
 public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {

     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OjaiLifecycleListener.class);
```

**My Branch**

```
macbook-pro:devel chris$ git checkout feature/mapr-autoinit
macbook-pro:devel chris$ git pull origin 

git diff feature/feature/mapr-autoinit..current_iteration  ./somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java diff --git a/somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java index 5d29f3eb..f0864c52 100644
--- a/somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java
+++ b/somepath/OjaiLifecycleListener.java @@ -14,7 +14,7 @@ import java.util.Collection;  import java.util.Map;  import java.util.function.Supplier;  
-@Component
+  public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {

     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OjaiLifecycleListener.class); @@ -52,23 +52,25 @@ public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {
     }

     private void createIfMissing(Class<? extends OjaiRepository> cls) throws IOException {
-        logger.debug("Configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
+        logger.info("configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
         // final Table table = cls.getAnnotation(Table.class); // No worky cuz of cglib
         final Table table = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(cls, Table.class);
         if (table != null) {
-            logger.debug("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
+            logger.info("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
             final String tablePath = tableAdmin.getEnvironmentQualifiedPath(table.name()).toString();
             boolean exists = tableAdmin.tableExists(tablePath);
-            logger.info("Repository => {},  Path => {}, Exists => {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);
+            logger.info("Table for class {} with table path {} exists : {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);
+
             if (! exists) {
                 logger.info("Creating table for class {} with table path {}", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath);
                 tableAdmin.createTable(tablePath, defaultTablePerms, defaultCFPerms);
             }
         } else {
-            logger.warn("Repository {} is missing @Table annotation", cls);
+            logger.warn("Found table without table annotation {} ", cls);
         }
     }  
+
     @Override
     public boolean isAutoStartup() {
         return true;
```

To me the patch above looks completely reasonable and should apply just fine. There are no duplicate common lines being changed.

**Merge**

```
git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-at-eol -Xignore-space-change current_iteration
```

This results in a large number of conflicts. However we can look at
the single file

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
@Component
public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {
=======
>>>>>>> current_iteration

public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {

<<<<<<< HEAD
    private final Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier;
    private final OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms;

    private volatile boolean isStarted = false;

=======
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OjaiLifecycleListener.class);

    private final Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier;
    private final OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms;

    private volatile boolean isStarted = false;

>>>>>>> current_iteration
    @Inject
    public OjaiLifecycleListener(Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier, OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.table.perms") Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.cf.perms") Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms) {
        this.ojaiRepositorySupplier = ojaiRepositorySupplier;
        this.tableAdmin = tableAdmin;
        this.defaultTablePerms = defaultTablePerms;
        this.defaultCFPerms = defaultCFPerms;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        logger.info("Configuring Ojai Tables");
        if (isStarted) return;

        ojaiRepositorySupplier.get().forEach(c -> {
            try {
                createIfMissing(c);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create ojai table: " +  c.getName(), e);
            }
        });
        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void createIfMissing(Class<? extends OjaiRepository> cls) throws IOException {
<<<<<<< HEAD
        logger.debug("Configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
        // final Table table = cls.getAnnotation(Table.class); // No worky cuz of cglib
        final Table table = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(cls, Table.class);
        if (table != null) {
            logger.debug("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
            final String tablePath = tableAdmin.getEnvironmentQualifiedPath(table.name()).toString();
            boolean exists = tableAdmin.tableExists(tablePath);
            logger.info("Repository => {},  Path => {}, Exists => {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);
=======
        logger.info("configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
        // final Table table = cls.getAnnotation(Table.class); // No worky cuz of cglib
        final Table table = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(cls, Table.class);
        if (table != null) {
            logger.info("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
            final String tablePath = tableAdmin.getEnvironmentQualifiedPath(table.name()).toString();
            boolean exists = tableAdmin.tableExists(tablePath);
            logger.info("Table for class {} with table path {} exists : {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);

>>>>>>> current_iteration
            if (! exists) {
                logger.info("Creating table for class {} with table path {}", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath);
                tableAdmin.createTable(tablePath, defaultTablePerms, defaultCFPerms);
            }
        } else {
<<<<<<< HEAD
            logger.warn("Repository {} is missing @Table annotation", cls);
=======
            logger.warn("Found table without table annotation {} ", cls);
>>>>>>> current_iteration
        }
    }
```

I have looked at whitespace issues and have tried every possible
combination of ignoring spaces. I have tried using their config
options along with the kdiff merge options. I have tried using
dos2unix tools to reformat the files. The only thing I can think of is
that this is an issue with the autosquash option not always replaying
changes correctly on my local branch. We are using TFS btw which is a
Windows git repository if that makes any difference.

**Update 1**

Apologies, I was renaming branches to make it more consistent with git standards. There are only two branches current_iteration and features/mapr-autoinit.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

<<<<<<< HEAD
@Component
public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {
||||||| merged common ancestors
@Service
public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements Lifecycle {
=======
>>>>>>> current_iteration

public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {

<<<<<<< HEAD
    private final Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier;
    private final OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms;
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OjaiLifecycleListener.class);
>>>>>>> current_iteration

<<<<<<< HEAD
    private volatile boolean isStarted = false;
||||||| merged common ancestors
    private final ApplicationContext context;
=======
    private final Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier;
    private final OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms;
    private final Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms;
>>>>>>> current_iteration

<<<<<<< HEAD
    @Inject
    public OjaiLifecycleListener(Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier, OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.table.perms") Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.cf.perms") Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms) {
        this.ojaiRepositorySupplier = ojaiRepositorySupplier;
        this.tableAdmin = tableAdmin;
        this.defaultTablePerms = defaultTablePerms;
        this.defaultCFPerms = defaultCFPerms;
||||||| merged common ancestors
    public OjaiLifecycleListener(ApplicationContext context) {

        this.context = context;
=======
    private volatile boolean isStarted = false;

    @Inject
    public OjaiLifecycleListener(Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier, OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.table.perms") Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms,
                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.cf.perms") Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms) {
        this.ojaiRepositorySupplier = ojaiRepositorySupplier;
        this.tableAdmin = tableAdmin;
        this.defaultTablePerms = defaultTablePerms;
        this.defaultCFPerms = defaultCFPerms;
>>>>>>> current_iteration
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
<<<<<<< HEAD
        logger.info("Configuring Ojai Tables");
        if (isStarted) return;
||||||| merged common ancestors
        logger.info("starting ojai listener");
        final Map<String, OjaiRepository> repositories = context.getBeansOfType(OjaiRepository.class);
        logger.info("found {} ojai repositories", repositories.size());
        repositories.forEach(OjaiLifecycleListener::createIfMissing);
=======
        logger.info("Configuring Ojai Tables");
        if (isStarted) return;

        ojaiRepositorySupplier.get().forEach(c -> {
            try {
                createIfMissing(c);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create ojai table: " +  c.getName(), e);
            }
        });
        isStarted = true;
    }
>>>>>>> current_iteration

<<<<<<< HEAD
        ojaiRepositorySupplier.get().forEach(c -> {
            try {
                createIfMissing(c);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create ojai table: " +  c.getName(), e);
            }
        });
        isStarted = true;
    }

    private void createIfMissing(Class<? extends OjaiRepository> cls) throws IOException {
        logger.debug("Configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
        // final Table table = cls.getAnnotation(Table.class); // No worky cuz of cglib
        final Table table = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(cls, Table.class);
        if (table != null) {
            logger.debug("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
            final String tablePath = tableAdmin.getEnvironmentQualifiedPath(table.name()).toString();
            boolean exists = tableAdmin.tableExists(tablePath);
            logger.info("Repository => {},  Path => {}, Exists => {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);
            if (! exists) {
                logger.info("Creating table for class {} with table path {}", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath);
                tableAdmin.createTable(tablePath, defaultTablePerms, defaultCFPerms);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Repository {} is missing @Table annotation", cls);
        }
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
    private void createIfMissing(Class<? extends OjaiRepository> cls) throws IOException {
        logger.info("configuring reopsitory {}", cls.getName());
        // final Table table = cls.getAnnotation(Table.class); // No worky cuz of cglib
        final Table table = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(cls, Table.class);
        if (table != null) {
            logger.info("Found table annotation for class {} with table id {}", cls.getSimpleName(), table.name());
            final String tablePath = tableAdmin.getEnvironmentQualifiedPath(table.name()).toString();
            boolean exists = tableAdmin.tableExists(tablePath);
            logger.info("Table for class {} with table path {} exists : {} ", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath, exists);

            if (! exists) {
                logger.info("Creating table for class {} with table path {}", cls.getSimpleName(), tablePath);
                tableAdmin.createTable(tablePath, defaultTablePerms, defaultCFPerms);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("Found table without table annotation {} ", cls);
        }
>>>>>>> current_iteration
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {
        stop();
        callback.run();
    }
```

**Update 2**

@Torek is helping me make sense of this now. He pointed out a command that I am unfamiliar with git merge base

```
macbook-pro:fido-service chris$ git merge-base current_iteration feature/mapr-autoinit
295c022c9f3d6da92e87f2addec1bbd7be30c5d7
```

According to the output this would explain the conflicts.

```
@@ -1,58 +1,97 @@
 package com.apc.its.services.fido.persistence.mapr;

-import com.mapr.fs.tables.MapRAdmin;
 import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
-import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
-import org.springframework.context.Lifecycle;
-import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
+import org.springframework.context.SmartLifecycle;
+import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;
+import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

+import javax.inject.Inject;
+import javax.inject.Named;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
+import java.io.IOException;
+import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.Map;
+import java.util.function.Supplier;

-@Service
-public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements Lifecycle {
+@Component
+public class OjaiLifecycleListener implements SmartLifecycle {

     private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OjaiLifecycleListener.class);

+    private final Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier;
+    private final OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin;
+    private final Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms;
+    private final Map<String, String> defaultCFPerms;

-    private final ApplicationContext context;
+    private volatile boolean isStarted = false;

-    public OjaiLifecycleListener(ApplicationContext context) {
-
-        this.context = context;
+    @Inject
+    public OjaiLifecycleListener(Supplier<Collection<Class<? extends OjaiRepository>>> ojaiRepositorySupplier, OjaiTableAdmin tableAdmin,
+                                 @Named("mapr.mapr.ojai.table.perms") Map<String, String> defaultTablePerms,
:
```

**Update 3**

I think I may have a handle on what is causing this issue. The reason I am constantly running into conflicts is that my branch is tracking two other branches. One is master and the other is a branch off of master which is current_iteration. It appears that my branch is deciphering the best

```
git remote show origin
... 

  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    current_iteration     merges with remote current_iteration
    feature/mapr-autoinit merges with remote feature/mapr-autoinit
    master                merges with remote master
```

This causes the merge to have to find a common ancestor which will be the last time that current_iteration was merged into master (which evidently has been some time ago).

This shows that git merge is attempting to merge from revision 1b813c6 which is months ago. This would in explain why changes are being reapplied etc.

```
git checkout feature/mapr-autoinit
Switched to branch 'feature/mapr-autoinit'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature/mapr-autoinit'.
macbook-pro:fido-service rkh477$ git show-branch --merge-base
1b813c6c48f1c11d65862331f6667258d536adf9
macbook-pro:fido-service rkh477$ git log 1b813c6c48f1c11d65862331f6667258d536adf9
commit 1b813c6c48f1c11d65862331f6667258d536adf9
Author: Somebody
Date:   Wed Feb 28 16:30:02 2018 -0600
```

I am assuming that I would need to rebase current_iteration with master to resolve this problem?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked end-of-line? Such a mismatch may create an all-file conflict. And it may be happening to you since both branches came from different OSes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked. Also with my merge I am using `git merge -s recursive -Xignore-space-at-eol -Xignore-space-change`

Comment: You're comparing two branch tips (`git diff feature/mapr-autoinit master`—the two dots you put between these names are irrelevant to `git diff` and are in effect just removed). `git merge`, on the other hand, is comparing one *merge base* to *each* of two other commits (perhaps those same branch tips). You get the merge conflict because the changes *from* base *to* tip-A conflict with the changes *from* base *to* tip-B. Find the merge base, or configure `diff.conflictStyle` to `diff3` so that Git shows you the merge-base version in the conflicted work-tree file.

Comment: Apologies @torek, I don't know why I replaced the branch name. The branch was always feature/mapr-autoinit. Does this make any difference? I changed the branch name back to it's original name feature/mapr-autoinit. I was always comparing master to feature/mapr-autoinit.

Comment: Do you have ruled out rights problems ? `git config --global core.fileMode false` would get rid of these type of differences.

Comment: You're still thinking of merge as if it compares two commits. Merge compares *three* commits. Find the merge base commit, and compare that to each tip. You need two separate `git diff` commands to see what `git merge` sees!

Comment: Thanks @torek. I am seeing how this is the issue. I am currently reading through  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base to try and make light of how this happened and what to do about it.

Comment: also remember that autocrlf only works on files that only have one line ending type. (a file with both CRLF and LF endings cannot maintain data integrity when line endings are converted, so it leaves them as is.) I've had this problem when one of the team members is using core.autocrlf = false on a windows machine. Also while ignore space options seem great, they often results in files with mixed line endings, so I recommend the `--no-commit` flag when you use one of those options and normalize the line endings before you commit.