# Git help to understand merge-base conflicts

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I am getting conflicts on files I have not modified. Conflicts on files with one line changes when merging. I am starting to get a handle on what might be happening but still unable to resolve the problem.

Here is the branch structure.

- master

  - current_iteration

    - mapr_autoinit

Master is quite old and has not had changes from current_iteration in quite some time. However master has had changes directly applied it by rebasing other bases directly onto master. So technically master and current_iteration have diverged. We have consistently branched and tag off of current_iteration. The problem I am seeing is that when I do a merge from current_iteration back into my branch. I get way more conflicts than should occur based on the changes to current_iteration. I am able to do a git diff / git apply from current_iteration and it applies cleanly.

When I run a `git show-branch --merge-base` on mapr-autoinit I see the commit was actually a commit on master months ago. However when I check `git merge-base current_iteration mapr_autoninit` I see that the version is very recent and most likely would not have conflicts.

From what I have seen for the last few days it seems logical that if I merge master into current_iteration, commit and then merge current_iteration back into master. This should probably resolve my branches merge-base to point to a more recent version.

Also is it possible that I could stop tracking master. I tried using `git config --unset branch.master.merge; git config --unset branch.master.remote` to stop tracking master but this did not solve my issue.

Is this a problem where the master and current_iteration have diverged and merge is trying to reconcile the merge by replaying the entire log?

Also here is more detail. I am opening a new question now that the question is much more specific. I will update both with a valid answer or delete the older depending on which is preferred.

[Git merge resulting in unreasonable conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680505/git-merge-resulting-in-unreasonable-conflicts)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've never found `git show-branch` output very useful myself and I am not sure how it is intended to be used, nor how others might use it successfully.

> Also is it possible that I could stop tracking master ...

This irrelevant.  What matters is the actual commit graph.  The upstream of any branch is independent of the commit graph.

> Is this a problem where the master and current_iteration have diverged and merge is trying to reconcile the merge by replaying the entire log?

No.  What matters *after* the merge-base-finding is only that—the merge base commit, that is—plus the two branch tip commits.  Everything in between is irrelevant.

> However when I check `git merge-base current_iteration mapr_autoinit` I see that the version is very recent and most likely would not have conflicts.

This is usually the way to get started, since `git merge-base` examines the commit graph, and uses it to compute the merge base commit(s).  Note that `git merge` by default runs the equivalent of `git merge-base --all`.  If this produces *more than one* merge base (more than one commit hash ID), you have a special situation.  Let's assume that you don't for now, but it's a good idea to check.

Having found that merge base commit, you can look at `git log` output (see the last section) and see how the merge base relates to the two branch tips.  Git does not care about this—well, that's not quite right: *after Git has found the merge base* (which depends on this), Git stops caring about it—but you might find it helpful.

Having found the (single) merge base of `current_iteration` and `mapr_autoinit` (and assuming you are on one of these two branches), here's what Git does:

```
git diff --find-renames <merge-base-hash> current_iteration > /tmp/1
git diff --find-renames <merge-base-hash> mapr_autoinit > /tmp/2
```

I redirected these to `/tmp` files here for ease of viewing multiple times and side-by-side or whatever, depending on your file viewer(s).  Since I don't know which direction you're merging—from what, to what—I just numbered the two files, rather than calling them "ours" and "theirs".  Note that the *combining changes* step is largely symmetric anyway.  For each change to each file, there are four possibilities:

- You touched the lines and they didn't: Git takes your change.
- They touched the lines and you didn't: Git takes their change.
- You and they touched the lines, but you made the same change: Git takes one copy of the change.
- You and they touched the lines, but made different changes: Git declares a merge conflict, and puts both sets of changes into the work-tree file.  If you set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`—I *highly* recommend this—Git includes the merge-base version as well, to show you what you and they *started with* before you and they made conflicting changes.

Viewing the results, with merge conflict markers and with the base version included via `merge.conflictStyle` set to `diff3`, is *usually* sufficient.  (In particular, it sometimes shows up cases where Git has *mis-paired* changes and thinks they conflict, when in fact the changes are to other regions that do not conflict.)  If not, it may help to look at the commit graph.

#### More about the commit graph

Something that *does* work, but can be difficult to make sense out of,<sup>1</sup> is the output of `git log --graph`.  It's helpful to include the `--decorate --oneline` options, and for this particular case, you will want to list the names of the current branch<sup>2</sup> and the branch you intend to merge.  For instance, if you have `mapr_autoinit` checked out and intend to run `git merge master`, you could run:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline mapr_autoinit master
```

Git will do its best to draw, in ASCII art with optional extra color added to help, the commit graph.  The result depends a great deal on what's in the graph, of course.  Here is a snippet from the Git repository for the Linux kernel:

```
* 1ffaddd029c8 (HEAD -> master, tag: v4.18-rc8, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Linux 4.18-rc8
*   a8c199208cd6 Merge branch 'x86-urgent-for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip
|\  
| * 1b3a62643660 x86/boot/compressed/64: Validate trampoline placement against E820
* |   2f3672cbf9da Merge branch 'timers-urgent-for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip
|\ \  
| * | 0a0e0829f990 nohz: Fix missing tick reprogram when interrupting an inline softirq
| * | 80d20d35af1e nohz: Fix local_timer_softirq_pending()
* | |   0cdf6d4607df Merge branch 'perf-urgent-for-linus' of git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tip/tip
```

One can use this to trace what has happened since the merge base.  There are more tools:

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --boundary mapr_autoinit...master
```

for instance will show you what's *not* merged (commits marked `*`), plus (due to `--boundary`) boundary commits that *are* merged (commits marked `o`) but without going any deeper into the graph than that.

For very simple cases—graphs that are not horrid with internal branch-and-re-merge—adding `--left-right` to the three-dot syntax is sometimes helpful as well.  For complex cases, with lots of internal branch-and-merge actions down each leg, `--first-parent` is sometimes useful, and `--simplify-by-decoration` is sometimes useful.

---

<sup>1</sup>Despite this, it's still worth perusing.  If you prefer, use a GUI or similar that draws the graph more prettily, but be aware that at least some Git GUIs seem to draw incorrect graphs (*cough*various*cough*webservices*cough*).

<sup>2</sup>You can always just use the name `HEAD`, in all capital letters, in place of the current branch name.  All-lowercase works on case-insensitive file systems on Windows and MacOS for instance, but it's not good to get into that habit.  A lone at-sign `@` means `HEAD` in any modern Git, though, so if you prefer, use that instead of spelling out `HEAD`.  Note that when using the two or three dot syntax (`A..B` and `A...B`), omitting one name entirely *also* means `HEAD`: `HEAD..B`, `@..B`, and `..B` are three spellings for the same thing.

Comment: I seem to have an issue with one persons' merges. It seems like his merges are causing my issues but I don't understand how it could happen. The branch origin/feature/predict-proxy-plot-endpoints seems to have created a crazy plateau of merges. I am trying to understand how this could be.

Comment: One gets this kind of construction when one repeatedly merges in rather carelessly (in terms of not caring about the graph, at least) from some source, instead of being careful (about the graph) to rebase (i.e., copy) commits to make them linear and understandable to future code-archaeologists. There are some people who like this kind of thing—see, e.g., the Git repository for Git itself—but for the last 8+ years I have tried to keep things more manageable at the places I have worked...

Comment: Note that whoever does the merge has control (as much as they want) over the final commit's tree. Some people make what are sometimes called *evil merges* because the final merge commit has something in it that does not come from either "side" of the two inputs (as compared to the merge-base). This can happen by accident, or on purpose, and sometimes it's a good thing despite the name "evil merge".

Comment: You can also experiment with *repeating* a merge, to see why it came out the way it did. Since a merge depends on the merge base and the two specific commits, you can check out (as a detached HEAD) one of the two commits (the two parents of the existing merge you're curious about) and run `git merge <hash-of-other-commit>` and see how Git merges those. If the result doesn't match the merge you're curious about, whoever did the merge must have done it with extra options, or as an Evil Merge, or something.